# Azure Key Vault - Geo Replication?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

Does Azure Key Vault supports Geo-Replication between the regions? I don't see any options?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried googling "Azure Key Vault Geo Replication"

Comment: Yes, I did. As per the documentation, it is all automated. However I have the application deployed on both West US (primary) and East US(secondary) and I want to sync between the regions.

Comment: In the rare event that an entire Azure region is unavailable, the requests that you make of Azure Key Vault in that region are automatically routed (failed over) to a secondary region. When the primary region is available again, requests are routed back (failed back) to the primary region. Again, you don't need to take any action because this happens automatically.

Comment: OK, I see.  You want to manually replicate one AKV to another region.  I don't think it's possible without backing up each key individually (I may be wrong).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/disaster-recovery-guidance

> "The contents of your key vault are replicated within the region and
> to a secondary region at least 150 miles away but within the same
> geography to maintain high durability of your keys and secrets. See
> the Azure paired regions document for details on specific region
> pairs."

Comment: As per the documentation, it is all automated. However I have the application deployed on both West US (primary) and East US(secondary) and I want to sync between the regions.

Comment: In the rare event that an entire Azure region is unavailable, the requests that you make of Azure Key Vault in that region are automatically routed (failed over) to a secondary region. When the primary region is available again, requests are routed back (failed back) to the primary region. Again, you don't need to take any action because this happens automatically.

Answer (score 0):

From @Karthikeyan Vijayakumar comment above:

> However I have the application deployed on both West US (primary) and East US(secondary) and I want to sync between the regions.

You don't need to *replicate* your Key Vault instance to make it available to your applications in both regions.

Simply call the URL (`https://<vault-instance-name>.vault.azure.net`), Azure DNS will dynamically resolve to the *active* region. By default, the active region is the region where you created the instance. In the event this region is unavailable, the DNS will resolve to the geo-replica, hosted in the corresponding [paired region](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/reliability/cross-region-replication-azure#azure-cross-region-replication-pairings-for-all-geographies).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this approach is that you still on the mercy of Microsoft, as the service will be reestablished only if they decide to failover the region.

Short story long: There is no user managed geo replication of Azure Key vault like Azure SQL for example. In your case, you need to build a workflow that replicates the values between your primary and secondary key vaults.

Backup and Restore : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/backup?tabs=azure-cli

You can use these capabilities to build your workflow.
You can use the changelog to track changes to your key vault, and trigger a backup/Restore or you can schedule it like once a day.

A change tracking is better as you can only replicate changes and not the entire key vault.
Regards